# Using the CALL Function in Neo4j for a subquery throws an error because of the '{'

Tags: neo4j, subquery

So i can use the CALL function in it's function as CALL procedure but when i try to invoke a subquery with CALL {} i get following Error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '{': expected whitespace, comment, namespace of a procedure or a procedure name (line 1, column 6 (offset: 5))
    "CALL {}"
          ^
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong, i found this procedure in the [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/). I'm using Neo4j Browser version: 3.2.15 and Neo4j Server version: 3.5.1 (community).

Thank you for your helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CALL` with subquery was introduced in Neo4j 4.0](https://neo4j.com/developer/subqueries/), so the syntax doesn't exist in 3.5.1. You'll need to upgrade to 4.0+ to get the functionality you're after.